# Get the size of a Draw2d Label Figure

Tags: java, eclipse, draw2d

if I have a class with a private `Label = new Label("");` in it and in some method i write:

```
private void setText(String text)
{
    this.label.setText(text);
    System.out.println("label size = " + this.label.getSize(0,0));
}
```

it will always print "label size = Dimension(0,0)". why is this? how can I obtain the size occupied by the label after setting its text? I also tried other solutions ([here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/65736/) and method getTextBounds() as suggested in [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/722990/) ) but i either obtain again Dimension(0,0) or a NullPointerException, respectively.

do you have any suggestion? thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.label.getPreferredSize()` is what you're looking for. It returns the space your label would like to occupy.
But at this point the label doesn't know yet what font to use, hence the `NullPointerException`. Once your figure tree has been set e.g. as the content of a `FigureCanvas` the font should be available. Alternatively, you could explicitly set a font before calling `getPreferredSize()`.

To add a rounded rectangle around your label, like you requested in your comment, you could do the following:

```
RoundedRectangle rr = new RoundedRectangle();
rr.setBorder(new MarginBorder(4));
rr.setLayoutManager(new StackLayout());
rr.add(new Label("label text"));
```

Comment: thankx a lot. actually i need the label size because around the label i want to draw a RoundedRectangle and i want to set the rectangle size as a function of the label size. i thought the setText would be the right place to adapt the rectangle size in case the content of the label is updated. any other suggestions?!?

Comment: @FSp: For a rounded border around you label, see my updated answer.